# Using a custom-made 404 page instead of theme's

Tags: html, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I've been trying to use a custom 404 page I created in my theme, and use that instead of the default one shipped with the theme. 
Since I'm not a pro at this, the way I did it is:

1. Designed the page I wanted just like a regular page.
2. Then I copied its source, (by viewing source of page) and created a new 404.html document.
3. I placed this file in both my child folder and then tried the root folder of my wp installation, (note I'm currently in dev mode).
4. I then edited my .htaccess file and placed variations of the following: *ErrorDocument 404 /404-page-not-found.html* (exact url of my custom 404), or just the */404.html* variation, at the beginning of .htaccess file.

Note: My theme has its own template of 404.php, but I don't see anything there in terms of a url to change and point it to my custom made 404.

Have I got this completely wrong? Can someone please steer me in the right direction? I just can't believe this is as hard to do ....?!

Thanks in advance for any help..!

Comment: Copy your 404.html to 404.php, that would be the best.. There is no need to develop a new file for this.

Comment: Hi there @HritikPandey and Happy New Year:-) Thank you for your time to help me out here. When you say 'copy' you mean the contents of my404.html document to the content of the 404.php? Wouldn't that create problems? Or o you mean to just take out/delete php and substitute it with my 404.html? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Hey @Tony, i mean if you are creating 404 page layout different than your website page structure then simply put the html content of 404.html to 404.php OR if you are using same header,footer for 404 page then just change the content between header and footer. Thanks again !!

Comment: Hey @HritikPandey, I'm being a tad daft here! I've made my 404 page using the theme's builder, just like any other page I've made. If I put the contents of that page in the 404.php, won't that create a problem since it's not php I'm placing but html?? Then you mention about changing just content in between header and footer - of which - the theme's 404.php?? Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: Update: Just gone ahead and tried copying pasting the html of my 404 in between the header/footer of the 404.php. It worked but not so perfectly since my html, (which I extracted from 'View Page source'), contained all info from website as well, not just that of the particular page. The reason I did that extraction was because the code from just my page, contains all sorts of shortcodes from my page builder, so I can't really put that within an html/php document. I'm a bit lost now and hope I'm making sense!?

Comment: hello @Tony, i can understand your problem but if the content is using shortcodes and other content dynamically as you said then you have to develop that 404 page according to your requirement.

Comment: Hi @HritikPandey, perhaps I haven't made myself very clear. I already made the 404 page according to my requirement, but my problem is, how do I display it, instead of the default one? The above method of copying, only half worked and displayed my header twice and looked messy. I'm sure there are more ways to achieve that. It's just a matter of discovering how!

Answer (score 0):

if you have already created 404 page and want to show that page instead of default 404 page then this code can help you out..

```
function redirect_404_custom() {
    if (is_404()) {
       // wp_redirect( home_url() ); //Redirecting to homepage
        // using a hard-coded URL.
        wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/some/page' );
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_404_custom' );
```

Comment: Hi there @Hritik Pandey - thank you so much for the code. You mention that I can redirect to my custom url for the 404 I created, however, the code has a 'home_url' variable. Where do I define the custom 404 url? Sorry I'm not advanced at this so trying to make sure I understand the code! I really appreaciate your patience with me..!

Comment: Hi @Tony, i have updated my answer, you can redirect like this also..

Answer (score 0):

Hi there @Hritik Pandey

I finally used a script that worked, just before you posted your last answer. I'm not going to alter it again for fear of the mess I may create again :-)
This is the script that worked for me:

```
    <?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: yoururl.com/");
exit();
?>
```

Thanks for all your patience and help. I really appreciate it!!!